# Converter data MMMM-YYYY para dd/mm/yyyy datepicker bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-3, datepicker

Tenho o seguinte campo de data:

```
<div class='input-group date input-data' id='datetimepicker4'>
    <input type='text' name="mes" id="mes" class="form-control hidden" />
    <span class="input-group-addon hidden">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div> 

 $('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MMMM-YYYY',
    locale: 'pt-br',
    defaultDate: new Date() 
});
```

Nesse formato é exibido: setembro-2016. Como exibo nesse formato e depois converto para 01/09/2016?

Comment: Tentou usar um option chamado `formatDate: 'Y/m/d'` ?

Comment: No server, quem vai processar essa informação? PHP, Java...
Não acha melhor tratar lá, ou precisa da informação tratada ainda no lado do cliente?

Comment: Aconteceu isso comigo e eu tive que usar o plugin `moment` para resolver meu problema ao selecionar uma data.

Comment: @KennyRafael php

Comment: Nesse caso seria possível enviar como na visualização e tratar no lado no PHP ou você quer que trate já na tela para o usuário?

Comment: Porque iria exibir das duas maneiras, mas acredito que tratando para PHP já resolva mesmo.

Comment: Uma variação do datetimepicke do bootstrap, achei bem completo, https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/

Answer (score 2):

No PHP, podemos criar uma função chamada `converterData`, e nela retornar o mês e ano no formato que você deseja.

```
<?php

$data = "setembro-2016";

function converterData($data) {
  $meses = Array(
    "janeiro" => "01",
    "fevereiro" => "02",
    "março" => "03",
    "abril" => "04",
    "maio" => "05",
    "junho" => "06",
    "julho" => "07",
    "agosto" => "08",
    "setembro" => "09",
    "outubro" => "10",
    "novembro" => "11",
    "dezembro" => "12"
  );
  $data = explode("-", $data);
  $mes = $meses[$data[0]];
  $ano = $data[1];
  return "01/$mes/$ano";
}

print converterData($data);
# -> 01/09/2016

?>
```